# When I try and execute this code, it returns an error 'Wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'getBookDetails'. Any idea why?

Tags: sql, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getBookDetails (d_title            OUT VARCHAR2,
                                            d_author           OUT VARCHAR2,
                                            d_description      OUT VARCHAR2,
                                            d_date_published   OUT DATE,
                                            d_isbn             OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   SELECT title,
          author,
          description,
          date_published,
          isbn
     INTO d_title,
          d_author,
          d_description,
          d_date_published,
          d_isbn
     FROM books
    WHERE isbn = d_isbn;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Book Author'
      || d_author
      || ' Title '
      || d_title
      || 'Description'
      || d_description
      || 'Date Published'
      || d_date_published);
END getBookDetails;
```

Comment: how do you call the procedure?

Comment: BEGIN

 getBookDetails(‘*isbn number here*)*

END;

Comment: you cant call it that way if you are using OUT parameters. You have to declare the variables for the OUT parameters and then call the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a `CREATE PROCEDURE`, which is kind of *wrong* - D_ISBN you use in WHERE clause is declared as an OUT parameter - should most probably be IN.

Anyway, we need to see the way you call it. Should be something like this: you need to declare all variables that the procedure uses as OUT (i.e. you have to *store* those values somewhere):

**[EDIT: included the whole "solution"]**

Create table and insert sample data:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE books
  2    ( isbn           VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  3      title          VARCHAR2(200),
  4      description    VARCHAR2(2000),
  5      author         VARCHAR2(200),
  6      date_published DATE,
  7      page_count     NUMBER );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO books VALUES
  2  ('123-456-789-0', 'Inferno', 'Novel', 'Dan Brown', date '2010-10-30', 300);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO books VALUES
  2  ('1-56592-335-9','Catching Fire','First Hunger Games Book.',
  3  'Suzanne Collins',DATE '2009-09-01',98);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Create procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getBookDetails (
  2     d_title               OUT VARCHAR2,
  3     d_author              OUT VARCHAR2,
  4     d_description         OUT VARCHAR2,
  5     d_date_published      OUT DATE,
  6     d_isbn             IN     VARCHAR2)
  7  IS
  8  BEGIN
  9     SELECT title,
 10            author,
 11            description,
 12            date_published
 13       INTO d_title,
 14            d_author,
 15            d_description,
 16            d_date_published
 17       FROM books
 18      WHERE isbn = d_isbn;
 19  END getBookDetails;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Run it, using ISBN you provided:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_isbn             books.isbn%TYPE := '1-56592-335-9';
  3     l_title            books.title%TYPE;
  4     l_author           books.author%TYPE;
  5     l_description      books.description%TYPE;
  6     l_date_published   books.date_published%TYPE;
  7  BEGIN
  8     getbookdetails (l_title,
  9                     l_author,
 10                     l_description,
 11                     l_date_published,
 12                     l_isbn);
 13
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 15           'Book Author '
 16        || l_author      || chr(10)
 17        || 'Title '
 18        || l_title       || chr(10)
 19        || 'Description '
 20        || l_description || chr(10)
 21        || 'Date Published '
 22        || l_date_published);
 23  END;
 24  /
Book Author Suzanne Collins
Title Catching Fire
Description First Hunger Games Book.
Date Published 01.09.2009

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK over here, I'd say ...

Comment: This is the question I am trying to answer:

3. Write a procedure getBookDetails which accepts a isbn number and returns the books title, author, date_published, and  the number of copies. The main block should call the procedure with a isbn number and output the book’s details

Comment: So are you saying I can use my procedure, if I declare the variables as OUT values when I call it?

Comment: Code I posted *should* work; I can't test it as I don't have your tables, but - give it a try.

Comment: Yeah I did try it, it says d_isbn cannot be used as a SELECT/FETCH statement.

Comment: Bah! Sorry, should have removed it from SELECT. I edited code in my message, please - try again.

Comment: Uh so the procedure now compiles, however, when calling it, there is an error, it tells me there is no data to fetch. So I used one of my ISBN numbers where you've got =: 'xxx-yyy-zzz' and it compiles but doesn't actually output anything?

Comment: Make sure to provide ISBN that actually exists in the table. Also, include EXCEPTION section into the procedure to handle NO_DATA_FOUND.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely a record I have in my table, but still doesn't output via the dbms, despite compiling correctly.

Comment: That should not happen. Did you check ISBN letter case, spaces etc.? Run query (used in the procedure) in SQLPlus to verify that.

Comment: Genuinely don't understand why it isn't working, the dbms output should be within the script output section shouldn't it?

Comment: It would work in the procedure (as you put it) or in "my" PL/SQL block. Did you enable SERVEROUTPUT? If not, DBMS_OUTPUT won't work.

Comment: Yeah the block for execution i'm trying to run (the one you provided), I have SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; at the top of. Still compiles without giving any output.

Comment: Could you provide sample data so that I (we) could try it?

Comment: CREATE TABLE books (
   isbn VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   title VARCHAR2(200),
   description VARCHAR2(2000),
   author VARCHAR2(200),
   date_published DATE,
   page_count NUMBER
);

Comment: OK, now some INSERT INTO.

Comment: This is a record I inputted:
('1-56592-335-9','Catching Fire','First Hunger Games Book.','Suzanne Collins',DATE '2009-09-01',98,’100000001’)

I have a procedure to input this but it's too long to post here.

Comment: Thank you; I've edited my message & included *everything*, from CREATE TABLE to execution. Have a look.

Comment: Those changes you just made have made it work, thank you so much for your help! Got me out of a real pain there!